# Bootstrap 4 & Adsense: how to ensure center alignment?

Tags: bootstrap-4, adsense

What is the best bootstrap 4 element class to display responsive Adsense advertisements horizontally centered on [my webpage](https://allecijfers.nl/nieuws/statistieken-over-het-corona-virus-en-covid19/)?

I currently use

```
<div class="container-xl text-center my-1" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPAdBlock">
        <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
...standard google copy paste...
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block"
    ... </script>
        </div>
```

I.e. the [bootstrap 4 class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/) `container-xl` shows the div at 1140px or 100% at smaller devices. Text-center centers text and images, I am not sure about the effect on the Adsense content. I guess it does not work. my-1 is just a bit of margin on the height.

The `class="container-xl text-center my-1"` displays centered ads most of the time but sometimes the same advertisement is suddenly left-aligened (as below, snip of the same part of the page with the same code but a different result within 1 refresh):

[image: adsense image centered]
[image: adsense image left]

I can center items using the class `justify-content-center` in combination with flex containers. I.e. the bootstrap class `d-flex`. But if I use the class `d-flex` then the Adsense adds are not shown at all.

As explained “Adsense's responsive code determines the width of the iframe it inserts based on the width of the parent element in which it is placed. Normally this works fine because even when the parent element has no content yet, it still has a width because it fills the available width.

However, if your parent element is within a flexbox row which determines the width of its members based on their content, the width of this will be zero until content is added. So of there is nothing else in the box other than the Adsense code, at the time Adsense calculates the available width, it's zero.” in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955406/flexbox-causes-adsense-error-adsbygoogle-push-error-no-slot-size-for-availa).

For d-block, Bootstrap also includes an .mx-auto class for horizontally centering fixed-width block level content—that is, content that has display: block and a width set—by setting the horizontal margins to auto. But I do not want to set a width in order to remain rsposonsive...

FYI the [Adsense requirements](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183362?hl=en), e.g. "Responsive ads should not be placed inside containers with a fixed or limited height".

**Update with the HTML of the ad slot:**

For the first add on [the page](https://allecijfers.nl/nieuws/statistieken-over-het-corona-virus-en-covid19/), this is the end of the previous row & container:

```
</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Hereby the last div closes this element:

```
<div class="container-xl my-2 achtergrondgrijs90 shadow rounded">
```

So the active scope is:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="row achtergrondgrijs95 py-2" id="inhoud" style="height: auto !important;">
```

Note: the style is not in my source and must have been added by Adsense.

The second add which sometimes aligns left is within the same structure. Note that this add is of the type 'in feed'. Also, please note that I have another issue that the Chrome DevTools responsive display of my ads is incorrect, this is [open with Adsense help](https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/53575024?hl=en). This makes it hard to use DevTools to copy paste the HTML. Because the adds are all over the place in this mode. But this should be the important part of HTML of the misaligned add:

```
<div class="container-xl text-center my-1" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPAdBlock">
    <script async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block; text-align: center; height: 124px; width: 1005px;" data-ad-layout="in-article" data-ad-format="fluid" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3768049119581858" data-ad-slot="3938780514" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_2_expand" style="display: inline-table; border: none; height: 124px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 1005px; background-color: transparent;"><ins id="aswift_2_anchor" style="display: block; border: none; height: 124px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 1005px; background-color: transparent; overflow: hidden;"><iframe id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; border: 0px; width: 1005px; height: 124px;" ...........and a lot more... data-load-complete="true"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
    <script>
         (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the HTML for a session where the ad is displayed in the center:

```
<div class="container-xl text-center my-1" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPAdBlock">
    <script async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block; text-align: center; height: 200px;" data-ad-layout="in-article" data-ad-format="fluid" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3768049119581858" data-ad-slot="3938780514" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_2_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:200px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:1110px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_2_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:200px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:1110px;background-color:transparent;"><iframe id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;border:0;width:1110px;height:200px;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" width="1110" height="200" frameborder="0" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-........a lot more.... data-load-complete="true"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
    <script>
         (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
```

Note: the "display: inline-table" surprises me but that is the same in both situations.

FYI the class `achtergrondgrijs90 or 95`  is just `{ background-color: #e6e7e4; }`.

Comment: Why did someone down vote my question? What did I do wrong? If have added more details...

Comment: To clarify, the question is how to prevent left alignment that happens once in a while?

Comment: Thx, yes, I changed the title to clarify: how to ensure center alignment?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's happening. But can you post HTML of the ad slot and its parent in both cases? Wondering if adsbygoogle.js produces different styles in both cases.

Comment: I have posted the HTML. I am happy to use any (bootstrap 4) element or class within any hierarchy that displays the Adsense adds correctly and responsive. So no problem to ignore my set up if you know one that works! I will take any advice! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a good idea right now. I opened your site and saw misaligned ads but then tried to reproduce it and it was always center-aligned after that. I suspect there is some race condition between adsbygoogle.js calculating available space and bootstrap doing its layout. Have you noticed any pattern on when ad is misaligned? Another idea is to delay ad loading (adsbygoogle.push({}) call) until after bootstrap is "done" with layout if bootstrap has some kind of callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All **Adsense** adds seem to be correctly displayed at all formats now using the following hierarchy of **bootstrap 4** elements and classes:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container-xl">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
adsense code
```

I have done a lot of trial and especially error. The delayed loading

```
<script>
         window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
              (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            });
</script>
```

did not solve the problem. Also inserting a class that defines breakpoints here e.g.

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle container-xl"
         style="display:block"
```

did not help.

Note: to avoid empty elements if there is no add available it seems to work to only use a bootstrap container and row that has it's own content independent of the add -> only the direct parent element of the add (class col) has no other content. E.g. [this page](https://allecijfers.nl/gemeente/rotterdam/) is now to my satisfaction.